# Count and remove extraneous files (bash)

Tags: bash, count

I am getting stuck on finding a succint solution to the following.

In a given directory, I have the following files:

```
10_MIDAP.nii.gz
12_MIDAP.nii.gz
14_MIDAP.nii.gz
16_restAP.nii.gz
18_restAP.nii.gz
```

I am only supposed to have **two** "MIDAP" files and **one** "restAP" file. The additional files may not contain the full data, so I need to remove them. These are likely going to be smaller in size and/or the earlier sequence number (e.g., 10).

I know how to count / echo the number of files:

```
MIDAP=`find $DATADIR -name "*MIDAP.nii.gz" | wc -l`
RestAP=`find $DATADIR -name "*restAP.nii.gz" | wc -l`

echo "MIDAP files = $MIDAP"
echo "RestAP files = $RestAP"
```

Any suggestions on how to succinctly remove the unneeded files, such that I end up with two "MIDAP" files and one "restAP" (in cases where there are extraneous files)? As of now, imagining it would be something like this...

```
if (( $MIDAP > 2 )); then
  ...magic happens
fi
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What is the condition for a _unneeded_ file in your usecase?

Comment: At this point, I think I want to eliminate the smallest size file(s). So, in the case of the "MIDAP" files, keeping the largest two files.

Answer (score 2):

here is an approach

create test files

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do touch ${i}_restAP; touch ${i}_MIDAP; done
```

sort based on numbers, and remove the top N-1 (or N-2) files.

```
$ find . -name '*restAP*' | sort -V | head -n -1 | xargs rm
$ find . -name '*MIDAP*'  | sort -V | head -n -2 | xargs rm

$ ls -1

10_MIDAP
10_restAP
9_MIDAP
```

you may want to change the sort if based on file size.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful! Much appreciated.